# how to update multiple columns based on single 'when' condition

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to update multiple columns based on one condition and one more column based on a different condition. How do I do that?

**For ex.** I have a table A with three columns col1, col2, col3.

I would like to update col1,col2 based on one if clause and col3 on some other condition.

My query would be

```
update A set 
          col1 = case
          when < cond1 > then < value1 >
          end,
          col2 = case 
          when < cond1> then < value2 >
          end,
          col3 = case
          when < cond3> then < value3 >
          end;
```

and this works

I would like to know whether there is a better way to club the first two condtions to one to update two different columns. 
Also, I would like to know which is more preferable ? updating based on conditons as stated above or using two different  update queries to accomplish the same ?

Comment: What would be the else case for the `<cond1>` ? and `<cond3>`

Comment: `case` is the best you can get.If values are *fixed* and you dont need any manipulate, then `decode` might be a better option!